# compute geometric multiplicity when $A$ is over field $\mathbb F_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Define $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 3\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -3
\end{pmatrix}$ over $\mathbb F_p$.I am asking to find whether $A$ is diagonalizable when $p=2$.

I have find out characteristics polynomial $c_A(x)=-(x+3)(x-1)(x+1)=-(x+1)^3$ when $p=2$. So the algebraic multiplicity $a(-1)=3$. But I don't know the corresponding matrix for $c_A=-(x+1)^3$. How can I compute geometric multiplicity $g(-1)$?

Comment: compute $(A+1)^2$ and see whether it's $0$

Comment: With $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 3\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -3
\end{pmatrix}$ or with $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$? $(A+I)^2\neq 0$ for both of them.

Comment: in $\mathbb F_2$, so it doesn't matter

Comment: @user836844 If you are working over $\Bbb F_2$, then those yield the same answer. Of course, the second one is easier to work with.

Comment: @BenGrossmann The OP's matrix is evidently not diagonalizable, as $A+1\neq0$. What I wrote was about determining whether we have 2 eigenvectors, or just 1.

Comment: @user8268 I see now, that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to compute multiplicities.

You have shown that $A$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue with multiplicity $3$. If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ must be similar to $I$ (the identity matrix), which would imply that $A = I$. However, it is clear that $A \neq I$. Thus, $A$ cannot be diagonalizable.

---

If you still want to compute a geometric multiplicity (as the solution apparently recommends), then the usual approach is to compute the dimension of the null space of $A + I$. We have
$$
A - I = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 3\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -4} = \pmatrix{1&0&1\\1&1&1\\0&1&0}.
$$
This matrix has rank at least two because its first two columns are linearly independent. Thus, its null space has dimension at most $3 - 2 = 1$ by the rank-nullity theorem. So, the geometric multiplicity of $-1$ is at most $1$. However, because $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, its geometric multiplicity is also at least $1$.

So, the multiplicity of $-1$ is $1$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for explaining. The reason I asked is the solution says $g(-1)=1$, and I am very confused how to get that

Comment: @user836844 See my latest edit.